# Getting different video ids YouTube

Tags: php, youtube-api

code.google.com's API for PHP

I have used this function : function printVideoEntry($videoEntry) and got

> Video ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>  Watch page:
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY&feature=youtube_gdata_player
>   Flash Player Url:
>   http://www.youtube.com/v/YYYYYYYYYYYYY?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata

If I pass given video id it gives me error:

> Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message
>   'Expected response code 200, got 400 Invalid id'

And if I pass YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY from Watch page and Flash Player Url [both are same] I'm getting it what I need.

Help is much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Using this function for getting video entries

```
function printVideoEntry($videoEntry) {
  echo "<div onclick=\"ytvbp.presentVideo('".$videoEntry->getVideoId()."')\" >";
  echo 'Video: '.$videoEntry->getVideoTitle() . "<br>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo 'Video ID: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoId() . "<br>";
  echo 'Watch page: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl() . "<br>";
  echo 'Flash Player Url: ' . $videoEntry->getFlashPlayerUrl() . "<br>";
}
```

I'm calling print video function from

```
 function getAndPrintPlaylistVideoFeed($playlistListEntry) {
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
    $playlistVideoFeed =  $yt->getPlaylistVideoFeed($playlistListEntry->getPlaylistVideoFeedUrl());
    foreach ($playlistVideoFeed as $playlistVideoEntry) {
    $getandprintplaylistvideofeed_array[] = printVideoEntry($playlistVideoEntry);
    }
```

Comment: Apologies but this is first question form me on stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0):

`$videoEntry` should be a `VideoEntry`-object, which you can get based on an ID:

```
$videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry('the0KZLEacs');
```

Then you could call the function and set that as a parameter:

```
printVideoEntry($videoEntry);
```

Or you could edit the first lines of `printVideoEntry`:

```
function printVideoEntry($videoId) {
  $videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry('the0KZLEacs');
  //...
}
```

Check out the [docs](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Video_Entry_Contents) to see what information you can squeeze out of a `VideoEntry` =)